# Jasmine spy callFake not being reached when trying spy on a service method that is called inside ngOnInit

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, rxjs, karma-jasmine

I am trying to set up some unit tests for a component that uses a service to perform HTTP requests to retrieve information from a database. I am very new to angular and unit testing so please be patient with me. In my test I am trying to spy on the function named `getClients` (this function is essentially a handler for the service that actually performs the HTTP requests) and call a fake function using `callFake`.

The issue I'm running into is that the `getClients` function is not being overridden which leads me to believe the spy does not work or is not spying on what I think it is. I can tell that it is not being called because the failure message references something from the real `getClients` function.

**Test Code**:

My understanding here is that because the function I am trying to spy on is in the `ngOnInit` function I must define the spy first and then instantiate the component. I have also tried running the spy inside of `it` and that didn't work either.

```
describe('handleID', () => {

    beforeEach(waitForAsync (() => {

        spyOn(service, 'getClients').and.callFake(() => {
            let companyList = [
                {
                    COMPANYDESCRIPTOR: "Hello World Inc.",
                    COMPANYNAME: "Hello World Inc.",
                    CUSTOMERID: "abcdef123456",
                    CUSTOMERKEY: 123456
                }
            ]
            
            component.companySearchService.companies.next(companyList);
            return companyList;
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CompanySearchComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        service = component.companySearchService;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    }));

    it("should update component.companyForm.controls['selectedCompany'] to 'Hello World Inc.'", () => {
        component.companyForm = component._formBuilder.group({
            selectedCompany: ['']
        })
        

        component.pathToNameProp = 'COMPANYNAME';
        component.pathToIdProp = ['CUSTOMERID', 'CUSTOMERKEY'];

        let id = 123456;

        component.handleID(id);

        expect(component.companyForm.get('selectedCompany')).toBe('Hello World Inc.');
    })

})
```

**Actual function**:

For the sake of clarity I provided the `getClients` function below. `dbService` is the database service that makes the API calls. `makeAnApiCall` returns an `observable` and the `subscribe` just passes the data to another handler that determines what to do with the data based on the `source`.

```
getClients(endpoint, method, options = []) {
    this.loading.next(true);
    this.dbService
        .makeAnApiCall(endpoint, method, options)
        .subscribe(
            res => this.generateCompanyList(res, this.source.getValue())
        )
}
```

**Failure Message**:

The failure message is referencing the obversable subscription that is returned from the database service's `makeAnApiCall` method. This leads me to believe that the spy is not being created at all or is spying on something else entirely.

```
Failed: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')
    at CompanySearchService.getClients (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:6343:13)
    at CompanySearchComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/utilities/company-search/company-search.component.ts:98:39)
    ...
```

**Questions**:

1. Why is the spy not working?
2. Regarding the unit test, is there a *better* way to write unit tests when working with observables, promises, and HTTP requests that doesn't require completely avoiding them?

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: Have you tried putting console.log inside your spy to ensure it is in fact not being called.  I'm uncertain that `component.companySearchService.companies.next(companyList);` is working in your spy the way you are expecting.

Comment: @E.Maggini Yeah, that was one of the first things I tried. `companies` is a `behaviorSubject` and inside ngOnInit a subscription is added to catch values emitted from `companies`. There is also no other place `subscribe` is being used this way.

Comment: It would be useful if you could post complete code for unit under test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution solves my problem, but it still doesn't really *answer* my questions. So if anyone can shed some extra light on this, I'd be happy to mark their response as the accepted answer.

**The unit test**

It looks like the order with which I was calling `spyOn`, `fixture.detectChanges`, and `component.ngOnInit` was messing with the service and thus my `Cannot read properties of undefined` error. The updated code below is the full unit test. I created `__beforeEach` so I didn't have to repeat everything inside the nested unit test. I eventually also did away with calling `component.ngOnInit()` entirely because it seems `detectChanges` works just as well.

```
describe('CompanySearchComponent', () => {

    let fixture, component, service;

    let __beforeEach = () => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CompanySearchComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        service = component.companySearchService;
        
        component.companySource = 'database';
        spyOn(service, 'getClients').and.callFake(() => {
            let response = { data: { rows:[
                        {
                            COMPANYDESCRIPTOR: "Hello World Inc.",
                            COMPANYNAME: "Hello World Inc.",
                            CUSTOMERID: "abcdef123456",
                            CUSTOMERKEY: 123456
                        }
                    ]}}
             component.companySearchService.generateCompanyList(response, 'database');
        });

        fixture.detectChanges();
    }

    beforeAll(waitForAsync(__beforeEach));

    it ('should initialize the component and the service', () => {
        expect(component).toBeDefined();
        expect(service).toBeDefined();
    })

    it ('should initalize pathToNameProp to \'COMPANYNAME\' and pathToProp to [\'CUSTOMERID\', \'CUSTOMERKEY\'] with source set to \'database\'', () => {
        expect(component.pathToNameProp).toBe('COMPANYNAME');
        expect(component.pathToIdProp).toEqual(['CUSTOMERID', 'CUSTOMERKEY']);
    })

    it ('should update companies array', () => {
        expect(component.companies).toEqual([
            {
                COMPANYDESCRIPTOR: "Hello World Inc.",
                COMPANYNAME: "Hello World Inc.",
                CUSTOMERID: "abcdef123456",
                CUSTOMERKEY: 123456
            }
        ]);
    })

    describe('handleID', () => {
        
        beforeAll(waitForAsync(__beforeEach));

        it("should update selectedCompany form'", () => {
            let id = '123456';
            component.handleID(id);
            expect(component.companyForm.controls['selectedCompany'].value.COMPANYNAME).toBe('Hello World Inc.');
        })
    })
})
```

**Setting the source**

It might not be relevant, but I wanted to bring up another issue I ran into. This component is not stand-alone and other components import it as a dependency. That said, had to explicitly define `companySearchComponent.companySource` and then reinitialize the component because it's value is defined in the constructor.

```
constructor(
    private elem: ElementRef,
    public companySearchService: CompanySearchService,
    private hierarchyService: HierarchyService, 
    private _formBuilder: FormBuilder
) {
    this.companySource = this.elem.nativeElement.dataset.companySrc;
    this.prevCompanySrc = this.companySearchService.source.getValue();
}
```

The constructor references the selector element for the source

```
<company-search [hidden]="!showSearch" id="company-search" data-company-src="database"></company-search>
```

Inside `companySearchComponent.ngOnInit` that source value is used to define some important properties for http requests and responses. It's also used in the initial call to `companySearchService.getClients()` (the function I was originally having a problem with).

```
ngOnInit() {

    switch(this.companySource) {
        case 'database':
            ...
            this.pathToNameProp = 'COMPANYNAME';
            this.pathToIdProp = ['CUSTOMERID', 'CUSTOMERKEY'];
            break;
        ...
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (!this.companySearchService.companies.value || this.prevCompanySrc !== this.companySource) {
        this.companySearchService.source.next(this.companySource);
        this.companySearchService.getClients(this.endpoint, this.httpMethod, this.httpOptions);
    }

    ...
}
```

Like I said, this doesn't quite answer the questions that I asked, but it is a solution to the problem so if anyone posts a more comprehensive and thorough solution I will gladly mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you're missing to do a `TestBed.configureTestingModule` before creating the component. This is needed to declare the component under test and provide the services similar to a normal ngModule. Best check [the Angular testing guide](https://angular.io/guide/testing#more-information-on-testing) to learn how to use it.

In the testing module you will set the CompanySearchService in the providers array and then you can access it with `TestBed.inject(CompanySearchService)` and mock the method you want.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I actually have a testing environment initializer set up in the main app module. All of the components are imported using this single module. I did figure out the issue though. It has something to do with the order I was calling `fixture.detectChanges` and `component.ngOnInit`.

Comment: Glad that you could solve your issue :). Also be aware that you usually do not have to call `ngOnInit` in tests. The first time you call `fixture.detectChanges` (i.e. the first change detection cycle is done), `ngOnInit` will automatically be triggered.

Comment: I thought so! I eventually did away with the `ngOnInit` calls entirely because it seemed to be redundant. Thank you for confirming my suspicions!